# Java: assign final variable in subclass before super

Tags: java

I have a class A which contains a final int, valA.

I have a subclass B which contains a large final object, objB.

The value of valA depends on objB which is passed in with B's constuctor.

How can I create an instance of B?

I've included minimal code for what I'm trying to do.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new B(3).valA);
    }
    static class A{
        final int valA;
        A(int valA) {
            this.valA = valA;
        }
    }
    static class B extends A{
        final Object objB;
        B(int initVal) {
            this.objB = someMethod(initVal);
            super(objB.hashCode()+1);
        }
    }
    Object someMethod(int initVal){
        // pretend there's some super complicated logic that returns a large object
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you switched the order of these lines: `this.valB = valB; super(valB+1);` ?

Comment: Yes very sorry, I dumbed down my original problem too much. The subclasses final variable is actually a very large object, not an int. So I want to instantiate it only once, use it to create the final int valA, but still have that object around as an instance variable.

Comment: You can't win here - the `super` call _must_ be the first thing in a constructor, and the compiler won't let you make reference to `this` in the `B` constructor (which includes calling non-static methods of `B`) until after the `super` call has returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super constructor call has to be the first statement in your constructor. Hence, `B` should look like this:

```
static class B extends A{
    final int valB;
    B(int valB) {
        super(valB+1);
        this.valB = valB;
    }
}
```

Besides, you cannot make any references to instance methods from the super constructor call. You could make `initC()` a `static` method, but that would defeat its purpose, as you could no longer assign instance variables from within `initC()`

#### Given the updated question...

You cannot work around this initialisation problem, which is actually a design problem. I suggest you extract the construction of your very large object to an external "Factory" and reduce the complexity of `A`'s and `B`'s initialisation, keeping constructors as slim as possible.

Comment: Very sorry, in minimizing my problem for posting I actually made it too simple. I edited the code to more accurately represent the problem. valB is actually a large object (large as in I only want to instantiate it once), not an int.

Comment: @ahbutfore: I understand. I tend to run into this problem quite often, myself. See the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use an overloaded constructor in B. In code below someMethod has been made static, alternatively it could be a final member method  in B.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new B(3).valA);
    }
    static class A{
        final int valA;
        A(int valA) {
            this.valA = valA;
        }
    }
    static class B extends A{
        final Object objB;
        B(int initVal) {
            this(someMethod(initVal));
        }
        private B(Object objB) {
            super(objB.hashCode()+1);
            this.objB = objB;
        }
    }
    static Object someMethod(int initVal){
        // pretend there's some super complicated logic that returns a large object
        return new Object();
    }
}
```